# Libvirt `--location` for $OperatingSystem

Tags: virt-manager

I'm trying to install a virtual machine (libvirt + qemu kvm) and I would like to fetch the operating system from network. I'm using the `--location` option.

While I know that CentOS can be started with `--location http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/`, I'd like to know what URL I should use, for example, to start a Debian. Some hints are provided in the manpages, but are not always correct.

To generalize, I would like to know what the `--location` option is actually searching in the given URL, so that I can spawn any distribution. The manual mentions a *location containing an installable distribution image*, but it does not define what an *installable distribution image* is.

Any hint? Is this some distribution-dependent bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the source code for the [urldetect.py](https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/blob/master/virtinst/urldetect.py) module in virt-manager source tree. The module defines how the location URLs are interpreted.

The proper *location URL* for a given distro depends on the distro itself. The `urldetect.py` module looks at the URL and attempts to decipher what distro it refers to and figures out the rest from there.

This means *installable distribution image* is a broad concept which refers to distribution-specific URLs virt-manager knows how to decipher.